# Pulling Django variable data using Python

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping

I am currently working on a project to grab live match data for eSports (yeah I'm a nerd, aren't we all?).  So I am pulling HTML from a page and checking if my favorite team is playing and if so, go the page and check the scores every few minutes to get updates.  The part I am now having trouble with is getting the names of teams and the match ID's.  The reason for this is because when I grab the HTML data, inline JS variable names are included instead of their values which is what I need.  Here is an example of what I am talking about:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 schedule-{[{schedule.state}]}" ng-if="schedules.length&gt;0" ng-repeat="schedule in schedules track by schedule._id">
```

I need a way to grab the value of "schedule.state".  Hopefully you guys can help.  Also if there is already a similar solution I would be happy to be directed to it! Cheers!

**EDIT**

I have just realized through a little more researech that the variables are not JS but Django.  Given the same problem just on how to get Django variable data instead of JS.

Comment: This is not Django templating language, looking at the syntax it should be Angular.

Comment: Use Selenium, which will render the page (and execute the javascript).

Comment: listen to @BurhanKhalid, he's right use Selenium